# Cypher - Multiple mapping when loadiing CSV files

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm a beginner with Cypher language (Neo4J) and I have try to find an answer to my problem without success.
I have loaded successfully nodes for Year(year), Month(month) and Day(day) with Has_Month and Has_Day relationship.
I also load successfully Airports(airportCode) node.

Now, I have a CSV file with these data:

```
Origin,YearDeparture,MonthDeparture,DayDeparture
AGP,2018,02,16
CDG,2017,05,24
...
```

I want to create a relationship between Day and Origin (which is an Airport already created).
I need to do something like this pseudocode:

```
if YearDeparture = Year.year AND
MonthDeparture = Month.month AND
DayDeparture = Day.day AND
Origin = Airport.airportCode then
CREATE (d)-[:HAS_AIRPORT]->(a)
(where d is a Day and a is an airport)
```

I have try this code without success:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "File:///AirportLinkedToDay.csv" AS csvLine
WITH csvLine WHERE NOT csvLine.Origin IS NULL
MATCH (y:Year {year: csvLine.YearDeparture})
MATCH (m:Month {month: csvLine.MonthDeparture})
MATCH (d:Day {day: csvLine.DayDeparture})
MATCH (a:AIRPORT {airportCode: csvLine.Origin })
MATCH (y)-[:HAS_MONTH]->(m)-[:HAS_DAY]->(d)
MERGE (d)-[:HAS_AIRPORT]->(a)
```

Many thanks for your help.
And don't hesitate if something is unclear.
M.

Update: Code to create hierarchical dates parts (Year,Month,Day nodes):

```
WITH range(2012, 2025) AS years, range(1,12) as months
FOREACH(year IN years | 
 MERGE (y:Year {year: year})
 FOREACH(month IN months | 
   CREATE (m:Month {month: month})
   MERGE (y)-[:HAS_MONTH]->(m)
   FOREACH(day IN (CASE 
                     WHEN month IN [1,3,5,7,8,10,12] THEN range(1,31) 
                     WHEN month = 2 THEN 
                       CASE
                         WHEN year % 4 <> 0 THEN range(1,28)
                         WHEN year % 100 <> 0 THEN range(1,29)
                         WHEN year % 400 = 0 THEN range(1,29)
                         ELSE range(1,28)
                       END
                     ELSE range(1,30)
                   END) |      
     CREATE (d:Day {day: day})
     MERGE (m)-[:HAS_DAY]->(d))))
```

Update: Code to create Airport Nodes:

```
 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "File:///Airports.csv" AS csvLine
 CREATE (p:AIRPORT { airportCode: csvLine.Code })
```

Comment: Are your relationship types `Has_Month`/`Has_Day` or `HAS_MONTH`/`HAS_DAY`? Capitalization is significant.

Comment: Also, if you only have 31 `Day` nodes, then `(d)-[:HAS_AIRPORT]->(a)` is going to be very ambiguous. For example, there would be no way to know which month or year is intended for the `Day` node with day value 1 -- since all months and years will have a "day 1".

Comment: Yes, HAS_MONTH and HAS_DAY are the right syntax. My error when I wrote the first paragraph

Comment: I don't have only 31 days. I have all days from 2012/01/01 to 2025/12/31 with a relation YEAR->MONTH->DAY

Comment: This is exactly what I'm searching for. How to link not only the day but also the month and the year corresponding to the date in the CSV

Comment: At the end, I want to know that an Airport named AGP is linked to the day 16 of the month 2 (February) of the year 2018

Comment: But another Airport can also be linked to the 2018-02-16 (for example: another entry in the csv can be: YUL,2018,02,16)

Comment: Can you add to your question details of what "without success" means? And are you sure you have all the required day, month, year, and airport nodes?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that all Year, Month, Day and Airports nodes are correctly created. And I'm able to visualize the link between year and month and between month and day. Airports have no relations.

Comment: "Without success" means that with the code provided above, nothing happens (message "No Changes, No records" appears)

Comment: Here is the code to create the hierarchical dates parts:

Comment: WITH range(2012, 2025) AS years, range(1,12) as months
FOREACH(year IN years | 
  MERGE (y:Year {year: year})...

Comment: You should put important information like that in your question, not in comments.

Comment: FOREACH(month IN months | 
    CREATE (m:Month {month: month})
    MERGE (y)-[:HAS_MONTH]->(m)...

Comment: Sorry, my first time here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was caused by the fact that `LOAD CSV` treats all input values as strings. In order to match against integer values, you need to convert input strings to integers via the `TOINTEGER()` function. For example:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "File:///AirportLinkedToDay.csv" AS row
WITH row WHERE NOT row.Origin IS NULL
MATCH (y:Year {year: TOINTEGER(row.YearDeparture)})
MATCH (m:Month {month: TOINTEGER(row.MonthDeparture)})
MATCH (d:Day {day: TOINTEGER(row.DayDeparture)})
MATCH (a:AIRPORT {airportCode: row.Origin })
MATCH (y)-[:HAS_MONTH]->(m)-[:HAS_DAY]->(d)
MERGE (d)-[:HAS_AIRPORT]->(a)
```

Also, your query will be more performant if you created [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) on:

- :Year(year)
- :AIRPORT(airportCode)

Comment: Many thanks, it is working well now. So simple. Thanks again for your precious help.